# Checks to be done, before/after changing the windows login password?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, logins

Here we have a scenario where a Service account , added under security as sysadmins for windows login, going to have its password change as per windows policy.

Since windows team, server admins are going to change the password, where should i check or what pre-activity should i consider before the password is changed.

This account (windows domain) is running the SQL services as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365941.aspx) for details about what to do on the SQL Server box.  This is taken from that page:

> The SQL Server Database Engine and SQL Server Agent run on a computer as a service using credentials that are initially provided during setup. If the instance of SQL Server is running under a domain account and the password for that account is changed, the password used by SQL Server must be updated to the new password. If the password is not updated, SQL Server may lose access to some domain resources and if SQL Server stops, the service will not restart until the password is updated.
>
> Change the password of the accounts used by the Database Engine and the SQL Server Agent in SQL Server 2012 by using SQL Server Configuration Manager.

If applications or other services are connecting to the SQL Server using that domain account, they will also need to know the updated password.  You may want to look at [enabling logon auditing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850.aspx) to help understand where those applications are.